# Clean session (Live Objects Orange)

Tags: orange-api

After the automatic reconnexion of the client MQTT, it does not receive any message, the subscription is not backed up knowing that the cleanSession = FALSE.

I need to know if Live Objects Orange support cleanSession = FALSE ??

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Live Objects doesn't use MQTT persistent sessions. You have to subscribe at each reconnection. If you want that your client gets messages that it misses offline, you juste have to use fifo topics. So that messages are kept in the fifo until a client consume them.

Best regards